# How to implement Pure DI with Razor Components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I am making an ASP.NET Core application using the Pure DI approach explained in the book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://manning.com/seemann2) (DIPP&P). Part of my application has a web API controller. To implement [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) with my controller, I was easily able to follow section 7.3.1 "Creating a custom controller activator" from DIPP&P to create a controller activator class, [similar to the example found in DIPP&P](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/blob/master/AopECommerce/src/Commerce.Web.PureDI/CommerceControllerActivator.cs). This was done by implementing `IControllerActivator` and composing my composition root within the `create` method.

My application will also feature Razor Components. I would like to continue using the Pure DI approach but I cannot find any examples on how to do this.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to implement Pure DI with Razor Components?
2. If so, how does one go about this?

Comment: The sample you linked uses the typical DI container to track all of MVC's dependencies. Except for overriding one service, which is used for constructing controllers? I'm not sure I understand the point.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - thank you for your reply. The [sample I linked to](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/blob/master/AopECommerce/src/Commerce.Web.PureDI/CommerceControllerActivator.cs) uses the `Startup` class to add services for MVC (`Services.AddMVC()`) and adds the `ControllerActivator` as a singleton service. Then the `ControllerActivator` is used to create the object graph for the application. The point of this is to avoid using a DI container, and create the object graph myself, within the `ControllerActivator.Create()` method.

Comment: You've described what it's doing, but not why. Do you know how many services are added to the DI container by calling `.AddMVC()`? What do you gain by avoiding this DI container for only your controllers and pages?

Comment: I gain total control over the DI for my application model.  I could use a different DI container framework such as [Simple Injector](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/blob/master/AopECommerce/src/Commerce.Web.SimpleInjector/Startup.cs) or [Autofac](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/blob/master/AopECommerce/src/Commerce.Web.Autofac/Startup.cs). You'll notice that the `Startup` classes when using these DI containers still use the ASP.NET Core `IServiceCollection` to `AddMVC()`. It's really just personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is possible to apply Pure DI to a Razor application, but not through `IRazorPageActivator` but through the `IComponentActivator` abstraction. Here's an example based on the default Visual Studio (2019) Razor project template. Since that template builds around a weather forecast domain, let's use that for the example.

Let's start with the custom `IComponentActivator`, which acts as your Composer, which is part of your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

```cs
public record WeatherComponentActivator(IServiceProvider Provider)
    : IComponentActivator
{
    public IComponent CreateInstance(Type componentType) => (IComponent)this.Create(componentType);

    private object Create(Type type)
    {
        switch (type.Name)
        {
            case nameof(FetchData):
                return new FetchData(new WeatherForecastService());

            case nameof(App): return new App();
            case nameof(Counter): return new Counter();
            case nameof(MainLayout): return new MainLayout();
            case nameof(NavMenu): return new NavMenu();
            case nameof(Pages.Index): return new Pages.Index();
            case nameof(SurveyPrompt): return new SurveyPrompt();

            default:
                return type.Namespace.StartsWith("Microsoft")
                    ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) // Default framework behavior
                    : throw new NotImplementedException(type.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice a few things with this implementation:

- Constructor injection is used with the `FetchData` Razor page.
- It falls back to using `Activator.CreateInstance` for framework components. `Activator.CreateInstance` is the behavior the framework uses for its default component activator implementation. Falling back is required, because there are quite some framework Razor components to be created. You don't want to list them all, and they are not yours to manage.
- In the `WeatherComponentActivator` class, I injected an `IServiceProvider`. It's not needed right now, but it shows that it's possible to use it to pull in framework dependencies if you need. There will certainly be a time where your pages directly or indirectly need a dependency on some part of the framework. This is how to integrate the two. The framework is so tightly mangled with its DI infrastructure that it's impossible to *not* use the DI Container for its framework parts.

Compared to the built-in behavior, using Pure DI has the nice advantage of being able to use constructor injection on your Razor Pages. For your `FetchData` component, this means it should be implemented as follows:

```
@page "/fetchdata"

@using AspNetCoreBlazor50PureDI.Data
@* "notice that there are no @inject attributes here" *@
<h1>Weather forecast</h1>
<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>
@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        Default template code removed for brevity
    </table>
}

@code {
    private readonly WeatherForecastService forecastService;

    // Yeah! Constructor Injection!
    public FetchData(WeatherForecastService forecastService)
    {
        this.forecastService = forecastService;
    }

    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await this.forecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Please be aware that even though your `WeatherComponentActivator` is now in control over the creation of Razer Components, the Razor framework will still try to initialize them. That means that any properties on the page that are marked with `@inject` are pulled in from the built-in DI container. But since you will not register your own classes in the container (since you are applying Pure DI), this won't work and your page will break.

The last missing piece of infrastructure required is the registration of your `WeatherComponentActivator` into the framework's DI Container. This is done inside the `Startup` class:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => this.Configuration = configuration;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();

        // Register your custom component activator here
        services.AddScoped<IComponentActivator, WeatherComponentActivator>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) ...
}
```

Notice how the `WeatherComponentActivator` is registered as a `Scoped` component. This important in case you need to pull in framework components from the `IServiceProvider`, because it allows resolving `Scoped` framework components, which is impossible to do from within a `Singleton` class.

But this has some important consequences. The examples of controller activators and other classes that function as a Composition Root often contain private fields that are used to store Singletons in them. This won't work for the  `WeatherComponentActivator` when you register it as Scoped, because those private fields will be gone with the next scope. In that case you should either store singletons in `private static` fields, but that has the consequence that it becomes harder to create `WeatherComponentActivator` inside unit tests, where you rather want a unit test to run in isolation. So if that's an issue, you can extract the composition of dependencies out of the `WeatherComponentActivator` into its own class, for instance:

```cs
public record WeatherComponentActivator(WeatherComposer Composer, IServiceProvider Provider)
    : IComponentActivator
{
    // Activator delegates to WeatherComposer
    public IComponent CreateInstance(Type componentType) =>
        (IComponent)this.Composer.Create(componentType, this.Provider);

public class WeatherComposer
{
    // Singleton
    private readonly ILogger logger = new ConsoleLogger();

    public object Create(Type type, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        switch (type.Name)
        {
            case nameof(FetchData):
                return new FetchData(new WeatherForecastService());
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This new `WeatherComposer` can now be registered as Singleton:

```cs
services.RegisterSingleton(new WeatherComposer());
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough example! So it appears that `IComponentActivator` is the interface to implement for Blazor components (".razor" files), but is it also the interface to implement for Razor Pages (".cshtml.cs" & ".cshtml" files)?

Comment: Crap! You are completely right. My answer doesn't make any sense in this context. Razor Pages are something completely different. We can do two things, either I delete this question and post a new one that actually answers your question, or... you change this question a bit to make it about Pure DI icw Razor Components, and post a new question about Razor Pages, and I'll answer that. I'd suggest doing the latter, so this answer is preserved, because I think it is a useful answer (but to a different question). Let me know what you think we should do.

Comment: No problem! I totally agree that we should preserve this answer so I'll modify the question and post a new question today.