# How is Pure DI implemented with Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

This question is similar to [my previous question about Razor Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074871/how-to-implement-pure-di-with-razor-components), but instead, this question is about Razor *Pages*, which requires a different interception point.

I am making an ASP.NET Core application using the Pure DI approach explained in the book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://manning.com/seemann2) (DIPP&P). Part of my application has a web API controller. To implement [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) with my controller, I was easily able to follow section 7.3.1 "Creating a custom controller activator" from DIPP&P to create a controller activator class, [similar to the example found in DIPP&P](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/blob/master/AopECommerce/src/Commerce.Web.PureDI/CommerceControllerActivator.cs). This was done by implementing `IControllerActivator` and composing my composition root within the `create` method.

My application will also feature Razor Pages. I would like to continue using the Pure DI approach but I cannot find any examples on how to do this. My assumption is I need to create a `RazorPageActivator` class, which implements [`IRazorPageActivator`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Razor/src/IRazorPageActivator.cs) and add my composition root to the `Activate` method. However, after reviewing the [`RazorPageActivator`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Razor/src/RazorPageActivator.cs) class found in the ASP.NET Core GitHub, it looks very complex and I fear if I intercept it (or override it?) by making my own class that implements `IRazorPageActivator` things will break and I'll be in a mess.

My question is how does one go about implementing Pure DI with Razor Pages, if possible?

Comment: And it's a duplicate, with no significant changes or clarification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074871/how-to-implement-pure-di-with-razor-components

Comment: Hi - if you read the comments to the answer of the other question you'll see why I posted this again. The response to my last version of this was for Razor Components, not Razor Pages. We decided to keep that response because if was helpful and repost my original question again.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. I updated the question to make it clear that it isn't. This question is about Razor Pages, while the other question is about Razor Components, which is a different technology. I voted for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Razor Pages, the `IPageModelActivatorProvider` functions as your Composition Root's Composer. Here's an example based on the default Visual Studio (2019) Razor Pages project template.

Let's start with the custom `IPageModelActivatorProvider`, which acts as your Composer, which is part of your Composition Root:

```cs
public class CommercePageModelActivatorProvider
    : IPageModelActivatorProvider, IDisposable
{
    // Singletons
    private readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;

    public CommercePageModelActivatorProvider(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) =>
        this.loggerFactory = loggerFactory;

    public Func<PageContext, object> CreateActivator(
        CompiledPageActionDescriptor desc) =>
        c => this.CreatePageModelType(c, desc.ModelTypeInfo.AsType());

    public Action<PageContext, object> CreateReleaser(
        CompiledPageActionDescriptor desc) =>
        (c, pm) => (pm as IDisposable)?.Dispose();

    private object CreatePageModelType(PageContext c, Type pageModelType)
    {
        // Create Scoped components
        var context = new CommerceContext().TrackDisposable(c);

        // Create Transient components
        switch (pageModelType.Name)
        {
            case nameof(IndexModel):
                return new IndexModel(this.Logger<IndexModel>(), context);
            case nameof(PrivacyModel):
                return new PrivacyModel(this.Logger<PrivacyModel>());
            default: throw new NotImplementedException(pageModelType.FullName);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { /* Release Singletons here, if needed */ }

    private ILogger<T> Logger<T>() => this.loggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>();
}
```

Notice a few things with this implementation:

- The structure of this class is very similar to the one's given in the [book's code samples](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/blob/master/AopECommerce/src/Commerce.Web.PureDI/CommerceControllerActivator.cs).
- It implements `IDisposable` to allow disposing of its own created singletons. In this case, no singletons are created in its constructor, so nothing needs to be disposed. The `ILoggerFactory` is "externally owned"; it is created by the framework, and will be disposed (if needed) by the framework.
- The class uses a custom `TrackDisposable` extension method (shown later on) that allows tracking scoped and transient dependencies. The `TrackDisposable` method will add those instances to the request and allows the framework to dispose them when the request ends.
- This is why the `CreateReleaser` method only disposes the Page itself. The disposing of all other created components is done by the framework when you track them for disposal. You can also choose to track the Page itself; in that case you can leave the `CreateReleaser` delegate empty.
- There is a handy `Logger<T>()` method that simplifies the creation of `ILogger<T>` implementations. Those come from the framework and are created by the `ILoggerFactory`.

Here's the `TrackDisposable` extension method:

```cs
public static class DisposableExtensions
{
    public static T TrackDisposable<T>(this T instance, PageContext c)
        where T : IDisposable
    {
        c.HttpContext.Response.RegisterForDispose(instance);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The last missing piece of infrastructure required is the registration of your `CommercePageModelActivatorProvider` into the framework's DI Container. This is done inside the Startup class:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // Register your custom component activator here
        services.AddSingleton<
            IPageModelActivatorProvider, CommercePageModelActivatorProvider>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, again, for your thorough answer. I was able to follow your example easily. You mention the `CreateReleaser` method can usually return an empty delegate. It looks like the [DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider.CreateReleaser()](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/Infrastructure/DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider.cs) method delegates to the `Dispose` method. Why not do that?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It would be good to do that, because that saves you from having to track the page itself. I'll update my answer to reflect this.